# Существует ли возможность узнать причину ошибки ввода-вывода в C++?

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

Не узнать из `rdstate()`, `badbit` или `failbit`, а конкретно что произошло. Или кроме чтения флагов состояния о потоках ничего неизвестно?

Comment: Проблема в том, что место реальной ошибки не совпадает с местом, где система эту ошибку обнаружила. Например, вы читаете из `cin` `double` и `int`, а там на самом деле `int` и `double`. После чтения `double` у вас внешне всё в порядке, теперь вы читаете `int`. Он считывает целую часть записанного в реальности `double`, и тоже рапортует, что всё в порядке. Наконец, вы читаете ещё один `int`, а он видит десятичный разделитель и выставляет ошибку. Вы видите, насколько далеко причина от следствия?

Comment: @VladD вот конкретно это и хотелось узнать, есть ли возможность ругануться, что не смогли считать к примеру int, и что вот в этом конкртеном месте всё посыпалось. Я так понимаю всё это придется руками реализовывать?

Comment: если вас интересуют ошибки формата, то лучше разделить задачу на чтение строки и последующее её распознавание. Например, прочитать всё до новой строки, а затем возвращённую строку уже как числа итд пытаться интерпретировать.

Comment: @borat_brata: В том-то и дело. Ну вот у вас должен было прочитаться `double`, а прочитался `int`, откуда стандартная библиотека узнает это? Или там должен был прочитаться `int`, но у вас текущая локаль какая-нибудь [тамильская](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_numerals), и в ней `1` не считается цифрой. Ну скажет оно вам, что не может найти цифр в строке, как это поможет? Система не знает, является источником ошибки неправильная локаль или неправильный тип читаемого значения, например.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Встроенных базовых средств, детально описывающих причину ошибки - нет.

Что произошло конкретно зависит от вызываемой Вами функции для потока. Но и тут не всё так однозначно, например `open` может вернуть ошибку как при отсутствии файла, так и при отсутствии доступа к файлу на чтение скажем. Чтобы узнать подробнее - надо делать более комплексный анализ ошибок средствами системных (а стало быть зависящих от платформы) вызовов.

При работе с файлами ситуация может измениться с включением в Стандарт C++ библиотеки [filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs).

Comment: "более комплексный анализ ошибок"—можно пример? Для простоты, можно Unix ограничится, где системный вызов open может пару дюжин разных errno значений выставлять. Я думаю вопрос автора можно интерпретировать как: предоставляет ли переносимое c++ API  более высокого уровня доступ к этим деталям.

Comment: @jfs в вопросе речь о `std::*stream`, и функция-член `open` оттуда же, а не системный `open`.

Comment: я знаю. Почему вы думаете я упомянул:  "предоставляет ли **переносимое c++ API более высокого уровня** доступ к этим деталям."

Comment: @jfs судя по комментариям под вопросом ТС нужно вообще просто числа читать разных типов. А переносимое API появится, когда `filesystem` в Стандарт включат.

Comment: вопрос (см. заголовок) в том, можно ли из уже существующего  API (iostream—см. содержимое вопроса) полезные детали об ошибке, такие как предоставляемые системным open, извлечь.

Comment: @jfs дополнил ответ.

Comment: @jfs вопрос задавался для всего I/O. Потом лишь было уточнение под свою задачу.